# Parse XML Schema Definition to CSV with Python

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I would like to parse the elements of an XML schema definition into a CSV file for documentation and analysis.  My XSD takes the following form;

```
<xs:element name="ELEMENT">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="element 1"/>
        <xs:element ref="element 2"/>
        <xs:element ref="element 3"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

For a given element name, I would like to create a CSV containing element 1, element 2, element 3, etc.

I've tried the Python lxml library but have not been able to access / filter by individual elements yet.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('doc.xsd')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
  print child.tag, child.attrib
```

Comment: Do you want those elements as columns or as rows? Btw, the xml above is incomplete and is not valid XML. Try updating it to minimal working XSD file.

Comment: I would recommend you using `lxml`. You have to install it and it take a moment, but than you have very powerful package with great xpath support, schema validation etc. And to follow up, go the tutorial [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is offering, it will answer all your questions.

Comment: Jan, thanks for the quick reply.  I have the full, valid XSD here locally.  This is a just a snippent.  I tried lxml but am getting stuck.  Using lxml, how do you find a specific element?  Once you find it, how do you access the sub-elements?  BTW, a list of element1,element2,element3 is plenty sufficient.

Comment: Tutorial explains few methods. One being xpath.

Answer (score 3):

Following code shows how to search XSD for element names.

```
from lxml import etree
xsdstr = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ELEMENT">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="element 1"/>
        <xs:element ref="element 2"/>
        <xs:element ref="element 3"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
"""

doc = etree.fromstring(xsdstr.strip())

namespaces = {"xs": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"}

names = doc.xpath("//xs:element/@ref", namespaces=namespaces)
print names
```

Running it prints:

```
['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3']
```

In case, you have more complex schema, you might need to target the names better, here is possible example:

```
print "trying more precise targeting ------"
names = doc.xpath("//xs:element[@name='ELEMENT']//xs:sequence/xs:element/@ref", namespaces=namespaces)
print names
```

In our case, the result is the same.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  This definitely started me down the right path.  I would up vote but I don't have the rep yet.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Find XSD to CSV parser as below:
With below code, multi-node XMLs can be parsed too.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def xsd_to_dict(xsd_path):
    super_dict = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xsd_path), "html.parser")
    for complex_type in soup.find_all('xs:complextype'):
        xsd_parsed = [x for x in ",".join(str(complex_type).split("\n"))
            .replace("</xs:sequence>", "")
            .replace("'<xs:sequence>", "")
            .replace("<xs:", "")
            .replace("</xs:complextype>", "")
            .replace("</xs:element>", "")
            .replace(">", "").replace("sequence", "")
            .split(",") if x != ""]

        if len(xsd_parsed[0]) > len("complextype") + 1:
            matrix_list = [e.split(" ") for e in xsd_parsed[-len(xsd_parsed) + 1:]]

            level_1 = ["|".join(["".join([":".join(final.split("=")) for final in y if len(final.split("=")) == 2])
                                 for y in [x.split(",") for x in item]]) for item in matrix_list]
            level_1.insert(0, xsd_parsed[0])
            for x in level_1[-len(xsd_parsed) + 1:]:
                flattened_dict = {x.split(":")[0]:"-".join(x.split(":")[-len(x.split(":")) + 1:])
                       for x in (level_1[0] + x).replace("=", ":").split("|")}
                xPath = flattened_dict.get("complextype name")
                xmlName = flattened_dict.get("name")
                dataType = flattened_dict.get("type")

                if xmlName != None:
                    final_dict = {x.split(":")[0]:x.split(":")[1]
                                for x in str("xpath:"+str(xPath)+",xmlFieldName:"+str(xmlName)+",dataPath:"+str(dataType)).split(",")}
                    for k, v in final_dict.items():
                        super_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    return super_dict



def xsd_to_csv(xsd_path):
    pd.DataFrame(xsd_to_dict(xsd_path)).to_csv(xsd_path.replace(".xsd", ".csv"))
    return "done"


xsd_to_csv("CustomersOrders.xsd")
```

input: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sample-xsd-file-customers-and-orders1`

Output:

```
,xpath,xmlFieldName,dataPath
0,"""CustomerType""","""CompanyName""","""xs-string"""
1,"""CustomerType""","""ContactName""","""xs-string"""
2,"""CustomerType""","""ContactTitle""","""xs-string"""
3,"""CustomerType""","""Phone""","""xs-string"""
4,"""CustomerType""","""Fax""","""xs-string"""
5,"""CustomerType""","""FullAddress""","""AddressType"""
6,"""CustomerType""","""CustomerID""","""xs-token""</xs-attribute"
7,"""AddressType""","""Address""","""xs-string"""
8,"""AddressType""","""City""","""xs-string"""
9,"""AddressType""","""Region""","""xs-string"""
10,"""AddressType""","""PostalCode""","""xs-string"""
11,"""AddressType""","""Country""","""xs-string"""
12,"""AddressType""","""CustomerID""","""xs-token""</xs-attribute"
13,"""OrderType""","""CustomerID""","""xs-token"""
14,"""OrderType""","""EmployeeID""","""xs-token"""
15,"""OrderType""","""OrderDate""","""xs-dateTime"""
16,"""OrderType""","""RequiredDate""","""xs-dateTime"""
17,"""OrderType""","""ShipInfo""","""ShipInfoType"""
18,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipVia""","""xs-integer"""
19,"""ShipInfoType""","""Freight""","""xs-decimal"""
20,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipName""","""xs-string"""
21,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipAddress""","""xs-string"""
22,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipCity""","""xs-string"""
23,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipRegion""","""xs-string"""
24,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipPostalCode""","""xs-string"""
25,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShipCountry""","""xs-string"""
26,"""ShipInfoType""","""ShippedDate""","""xs-dateTime""
```